# Error when trying to route user to specific page on notification click

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm getting an error while I was working on setting up the ability to go to a specific page when clicking on a Firebase notification. I had already had FCM working just fine, it just opened the app's home screen. Unfortunately, I don't remember what the last thing I did was. All I have to go off of now is this error below that happens when I try to run the app on my physical device. Any ideas?

```
adb: failed to install 
C:\Users\USER\Desktop\APPNAME\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: 

Failed parse during install

Package LI: /data/app/vmdl1292100858.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #163): 
    com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver: 

Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]

Error launching application on SM G991U.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problem:

```bash
Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]
```

From the error message above, your `AndroidManifest.xml` is missing the `android:exported` element in the activity.

### Solution:

Set `android:exported` to either `true` or `false` in your Activity with an intent filter.

> android:exported
>
> If an activity in your app includes intent filters, set this element to "true" to allow other apps to start it. For example, if the activity is the main activity of the app and includes the category "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER".
>
> If this element is set to "false" and an app tries to start the activity, the system throws an ActivityNotFoundException.
>
> Source: [android:exported documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported)

```xml
<activity
  android:exported="true"
  ...>

</activity>
```